# MongoDB taking last N password for each user

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that holds password history. Each element is something like

```
{ username: "Fooo", createdAt: "2018-06-04" }
```

What I want to take is the last N entries in password history, for each user, and update them to today.
I also have a collection with all the usernames so what I've tried is something like

```
db.getCollection('users')
   .find({})
   .forEach(function(u){
      db.getCollection('passwordHistory')
      .find({username:u})
      .sort({createdAt:-1})
      .limit(1)
      .forEach(function(p){
        p.createdAt = new Date("2018-06-04T17:00:00Z")
        p.save()
      })
})
```

But it returned `Script executed successfully, but there are no results to show`

Using mongodb 3.2.2

Comment: In the statement  find({username: u}), you possibly need to specify which field of the document you are comparing to. Example, it should be like : find({username: u.username}).  However, if you can share your schema, then the problem can be better analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

As shmit stated in the first comment, I was doing `find({username: u})` insted of `find({username: u.username})`